# How is $E×B$ zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

I was reading Feynman lectures vol. 2 pg no. 291. There I found the general solution of one dimensional planar waves along $x$ direction. My question is the when I apply dot product on $E$ and $B$ vector I don't get zero that means they are not perpendicular but the books says opposite. I can not find my mistake. Kindly help me.

[image]

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: (also, there's always a chance the book simply has a typo. I haven't checked the computation, but it is a possibility)

Comment: is there any relationship between $F$ and $f$ and $g$ and $G$, because it certainly looks like the cross product is going to be proportional to $\left(f^{2} - g^{2}\right) - \left(F^{2} - G^{2}\right)$.

Comment: The cross product is the Poynting vector so why should it be zero in a wave solution?

Comment: $\vec{E}\cdot\vec{B}$ is not necessarily zero for a superposition of plane waves.

Comment: @ProfRob yes but why did the author write that "At every point the magnetic field is always perpendicular to the electric field and ..." at the very next line below the general planar wave solution if this is true only for a particular case? Is this some kind of error in Feynman book?

Comment: @CWPP my question is related to dot product not cross product.

Comment: If $E_1$ nd $B_1$ are a valid solution to Maxwell's equations and $E_2$ and $B_2$ are another solution; then $E_1 + E_2$ and $B_1 + B_2$ is also a solution. We can say that $E_1 \cdot B_1 = E_2\cdot B_2 = 0$, but that does not mean $(E_1 + E_2)\cdot (B_1 + B_2) = 0$.